# Creating and populating form fields dynamically in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In the form I have a simple drop-down input list which is populated with data from controller.
Here is the input field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('label'=>'Employee'));
```

and here how I populate it:

```
    $employees = $this->User->getEmployeeList($this->Auth->user('company_id'));
$this->set('users', $employees);
```

Now I need to allow a user to create these employee drop-downs dynamically. I thought I would just use jQuery to add the HTML needed for the fields, but how do I populate them with the same *$employees* array?

Comment: you need Ajax to save the new item and retrieve the new option list to use inside the input.

Comment: Well I would only save the new item together with the remaining information once the submit button is pressed and the option list is going to be the same in every newly created field.

Comment: So let me know if I understand what you are asking: you want a user to select a company from a drop down and then the employee dropdown has to be automatically filled? Like a Country - State - City scenario?

Comment: User has to select an employee from the dropdown, and if needed, he can dynamically create a new field(s) for one or more employees to be selected through the dropdown that is exactly the same as the first one.

Comment: Similar to this one http://jsfiddle.net/aDeLf/, but I need to populate the fields with the same associative array

Comment: using only jQuery I think you can clonate an input as many time as you need. Once cloanated you have to change its id and name as needed

Answer (score 1):

You must write some javascript, or jquery plugin for do that. So in you view.ctp file transform this->User->getEmployeeList($this->Auth->user('company_id')) in to javascript variable. When you create new element in click event populate field that values:

```
var employeeList= <?=$users?>
$('#addVar').on('click', function(){
varCount++;
$node = $('<p><label for="var'+varCount+'">Employee '+varCount+': </label><input type="text" name="var'+varCount+'" id="var'+varCount+'"><span class="removeVar">Remove Employee</span></p>').val(employeeList);
$(this).parent().before($node);
});
```

Comment: I get the following error when putting the: var employeeList = <?=$employees?>

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < [http://localhost/scheduling/js/addemployees.js:1]

what is the proper syntax for it?

Comment: changed it to `var employeeList= <?=$users?>` but still get the same error at the first line and no javascript is being executed. PHP variable $users is an associative array by the way.